# Build error after upgrading dotnet core to 2.1.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have updated Dotnet-Core version from version 2.1.1 to 2.1.3 by these commands:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.App -Version 2.1.3
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App -Version 2.1.3
```

after updating to the new version on project building I receive this error:

> The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.3,
>   but with current settings, version 2.1.0 would be used instead.  To
>   resolve this issue, make sure the same settings are used for restore
>   and for subsequent operations such as build or publish.  Typically
>   this issue can occur if the RuntimeIdentifier property is set during
>   build or publish but not during restore.

I checked upgrading side effect by [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1) document.

So what did I missed?

Comment: Might want to give a read to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @HereticMonkey I read those pages before and checked my config every things seems ok

Comment: I found that downloading latest SDK and runtime fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade the runtime by just upgrading the nuget packages. You actually need to update the SDK/runtime itself using whatever mechanism you used to install it in the first place.

If `dotnet --list-runtimes` doesn't list the runtime (eg, 2.1.3), you wont be able to use it.